# How to get rid of the webpack source code on client side?

Tags: node.js, webpack, pm2

I deploy a node.js app on pm2 server which serves my client code with Nginx. My client source code is bundled with Webpack. It is supposed to be minified and obfuscated. But when I run my app on client side and I open the console log "source" tab I can see both the obfuscated source code and the webpack file structure which is located under a "top://Webpack" directory.

I don't want to show my code structure to the client. How can I get rid of that webpack file structure on the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This original file structure is provided by sourcemaps. Which is great because allows you to trace back errors in production code.

You have the following options here

- Disable sourcemaps generation by setting `devtool: false` [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool).
- Do not serve `*.map` files by removing them or by configuring nginx not to serve those files.

You could read a discussion why this is not that great idea [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1341)

Comment: Thanks I am using the option `eval-source-map` and I see the [Docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool) says `production: no`  . What does that mean? Which option do you suggest if I want to keep some track but don't want to show the code structure? Or is it better to use `devtool: false` instead to make it opaque to the users completely? There aren't many things to do on the client side. Everything runs on the server. The only commands receives from the client are some `mousemove` and `mousedown` events.

Comment: @newguy I believe `production: no` means it is not suitable for production. "I want to keep some track but don't want to show the code structure" i'd configure web server not to serve *.map files unless some header in request is specified or something. Though i don't see why you want to hide your code :)

Comment: Thanks I have changed `devtool:eval-source-map` to `devtool:false` and the webpack style source codes are gone. But I can't find any *.map files on my html folder even though Chrome console tells me it detects the source-map file called `blob.js.map`. I can't hide it if I don't even see it. Yes hiding my code is a special requirement for my project. It is a browser game so I would rather keep hackers away than getting more trouble for myself.

Comment: @newguy "eval-source-map" inlines source map into the output.

Comment: I know but I have changed it to `devtool:false` and also tried `devtool:nosources-source-map` . But Chrome still tells me that it detects the sourcemap when I click on the `main.js` file which is my app entry.

Comment: @newguy Hard to say w/o seeing your actual code. Idk clear browser cache, restart nginx...